# About the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^tA$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I don't know if the following is correct  ($^tA$ denotes the transpose of $A$).

> Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, and consider $S = A^tA$. Let $(\lambda_i)_{1 \leq i \leq k}$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, and denote $K = \{ \lambda_i^2 \mid 1 \leq i \leq k\}$. Now if $L$ is the spectrum of $S$ then is it true that $ L = K \cup \{1\} \text{ or } L = K$?

I think I have a proof of this fact but I don't know if this is correct.

So far here are my thoughts :

Let's say $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$ but not an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$. 
So we have : $A^tAv = \lambda v$. Since $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$ then the vector $a :=^tAv$ is not colinear to the vector $v$. So it means that the matrix $A$ sends the vector $a$ to $\lambda v$.

Hence if $O$ is the rotation matrix that sends $v$ to $a$ then there exist a matrix $B$ such that $Ba = a$ and $^tA = BO$. Thus since the tranpose of a rotaion matrix is it's inverse we have : $A = O^{-1}(^tB)$. Since $Ba =a$ it means $^tBa = a$ thus : $Aa = O^{-1}a = v$ since $O$ is the rotation matrix that sends $v$ to $a$ then it's inverse is the matrix that sends $a$ to $v$. So we have $\lambda = 1$. This means that if $a$ is not colinear to $v$ and $v$ is an eigenvetor of $S$ then the eigenvalue of $v$ is necessarily $1$. $ \square$

Is what I said correct ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried some examples where $A$ and $A^t$ don't commute?

Comment: @RobertIsrael No I haven't... There is an easy counterexample ?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh I see... What I am saying is only true when $A$ and $^tA$ have the same eigenvectors right ?

Comment: When they have the same eigenvectors, $A$ is a normal matrix, and then the eigenvalues of $A^t A$ are the squares of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $A$.  Your union with $\{1\}$ makes no sense.